# AcquireTokenSilentAsync fails to authenticate user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to get the silent token request to initialize the `ConfidentialClientApp` object as in the 'Microsoft Graph SDK ASPNET Connect' project and outlined in [Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp)

With my code mirroring the samples above, I expect that my call will return a successful result with an access to.

```
var result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphScopes, cca.Users.First());

return result.AccessToken;
```

However, I get an error where it says the user needs to be authenticated. I am not sure what I am missing from the examples that make this work in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only acquire the token silently if there is already a cached token for that user that includes the scopes you're requesting (it can have more, but it needs to have at least what you've asked for).

This is why `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` should always be wrapped in a Try/Catch block. If it fails to find a matching token, you need to launch an interactive flow. Here is an example from the [MSAL Wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token):

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, app.Users.FirstOrDefault());
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. 
    // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
    }
    catch (MsalException msalex)
    {
        ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
    return;
}

if (result != null)
{
    string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
    // Use the token
}
```

Comment: A few tweaks to this and I was able to get my workflow to the expected behavior. Thanks

Comment: Hi Marc,
How would you do this in the case of a aspnetcore web app?